# Angular auto form submit on validate with $watch

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

So I am trying to auto submit the form once it has been validated.

**HTML**

```
<form name="myForm" role="form" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" name="location" ng-model='calc.location1' required>
                <option value=7>Location1</option>
                <option value=9>Location2</option>
                <option value=5>Location3</option>
             </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type='number' name="Size" ng-model='calc.Size' placeholder="Sq ft" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type='number' name="units" ng-model='calc.units' placeholder="Units in kWH" required>
        </div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
myapp.controller('demoController', ['$scope', function($scope, $document) {
    $scope.$watch('myForm.units.$valid', function (newValue, oldvalue){
        if(newValue) {
            console.log(newValue);
        }
    })    
}])
```

I want to insert my form submit code inside the if statement, but newValue is always showing true even when the form inputs are empty at page load.

Trying to do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/EdCEW/ but no idea where I am going wrong.

Comment: Fiddle works fine for me. If I set any default value in `model.name`, alert message appears with the message 'Model is Valid' and if `mode.name` is empty, alert not appearing or am I missing something?

Comment: Or you may want to check all validations in one go using `myForm.$valid`

Comment: Fiddle is working fine, but on the actual app it isnt working, newValue is always true doesnt turn to false even on refresh. have tried checking all validations in one go as well.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is to create one method to validate all fields and set scope variable to true if all fields are valid.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController',['$scope',function($scope) {
$scope.checked = 0;
$scope.$watch('myForm.$valid', function (newValue, oldvalue){
$scope.checkDirty();

    if($scope.checked === 1)
    {            alert('Model is valid');
            //Can do a ajax model submit.
        }

    });
    $scope.checkDirty = function(){

    if($scope.myForm.Size.$valid && $scope.myForm.units.$valid)
        {
            $scope.checked = 1; 
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.checked =0;
        }
};
}]);
```

Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/EdCEW/92/

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you. Was trying to do something like this. Although now the alert is called the moment a single digit is entered in the input units field. tried using ng-minlength but then the alert will be triggered the moment that minlength is reached. Any way the user can finish entering the data(whatever length it might be) and then the alert is called ?

Im thinking timeout